# Scatterplot subplots with the same colors and markers

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter

I am creating a figure with two subplots with scatter plots.  I want to use the same color scheme and marker definitions for each subplot, but can't seem to get it to work.  Please forgive the length of my minimal working example, but I trimmed it down as much as I can.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as tkr
from scipy.stats import probplot

#Raw Data
area_old = [7603.4897489697905, 2941.7094279413577, 8153.896678990219, 7289.99097646249, 8620.196237363853, 11619.546945954673, 8458.80648310436, 7161.530990460888, 28486.298572761007, 4928.4856128268875, 4219.122621992603, 31687.155529782176]

combined = [7603.4897489697905, 2941.7094279413577, 8153.896678990219, 7289.99097646249, 8620.196237363853, 11619.546945954673, 8458.80648310436, 7161.530990460888, 28486.298572761007, 4928.4856128268875, 4219.122621992603, 31687.155529782176, 3059.4357099599456, 3348.0415691055823, 4839.023360449559, 4398.877634354169, 29269.67455441528, 11058.400909555028, 18266.34679952683, 16641.3446048029, 24983.586163502885, 5811.868753338233]

#Attributes to map colors and markers to
lt_bt = ['r','s','s','r','r','u','r','s','r','r','s','r']
combined_bt =['r','s','s','r','r','u','r','s','r','r','s','r','u','u','r','s','r','s','r','r','r','u']

#Get Probability plot Data
a = probplot(area_old,dist='norm', plot=None)
b= probplot(combined,dist='norm', plot=None)

#Colors and Markers to use
colors = {'r':'red','s':'blue', 'u':'green'}
markers = {'r':'*','s':'x', 'u':'o'}

#Create Dataframe to combine raw data, attributes and sort
old_df = pd.DataFrame(area_old, columns=['Long Term Sites: N=12'])
old_df['Bar_Type'] = lt_bt
old_df = old_df.sort_values(by='Long Term Sites: N=12')
old_df['quart']=a[0][0]

#Pandas series of colors for plotting on subplot 'ax'
ax_color = old_df.loc[:,'Bar_Type'].apply(lambda x: colors[x])

#Create Dataframe to combine raw data, attributes and sort   
combined_df = pd.DataFrame(combined, columns=['ALL SITES N=22'])
combined_df['Bar_Type'] = combined_bt
combined_df = combined_df.sort_values(by='ALL SITES N=22')
combined_df['quart']=b[0][0]

#Pandas series of colors for plotting on subplot 'ax1'
ax1_color = combined_df.loc[:,'Bar_Type'].apply(lambda x: colors[x])

#Legend Handles
undif = plt.Line2D([0,0],[0,1], color='green',marker='o',linestyle=' ')
reatt = plt.Line2D([0,0],[0,1], color='red',marker='*',linestyle=' ')
sep = plt.Line2D([0,0],[0,1], color='blue',marker='x',linestyle=' ')


fig,(ax,ax1) = plt.subplots(ncols=2,sharey=True)

#Plot each data point seperatly with different markers and colors
for i, thing in old_df.iterrows():
    ax.scatter(thing['quart'],thing['Long Term Sites: N=12'],c=ax_color.iloc[i],marker=markers[thing['Bar_Type']],zorder=10,s=50)
del i, thing

for i , thing in combined_df.iterrows():
    ax1.scatter(thing['quart'],thing['ALL SITES N=22'],c=ax1_color.iloc[i],marker=markers[thing['Bar_Type']],zorder=10,s=50)
del i, thing

ax.set_title('LONG TERM SITES N=12')
ax1.set_title('ALL SITES N=22')
ax1.set_ylabel('')
ax.set_ylabel('TOTAL EDDY AREA, IN METERS SQUARED')
ax.set_ylim(0,35000)
ax.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(tkr.FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: format(int(x), ',')))

legend = ax.legend([reatt,sep,undif],["Reattachment","Separation", "Undifferentiated"],loc=2,title='Bar Type',fontsize='x-small')

plt.setp(legend.get_title(),fontsize='x-small')

ax.set_xlabel('QUANTILES')
ax1.set_xlabel('QUANTILES')
plt.tight_layout()
```

The basic idea is I am plotting scatter plots, point-by-point, to assign the appropriate color and marker.  I assign colors using pandas integer indexing  `.iloc` and assign marker by specifying a key for the `markers` dictionary.

I know something isn't right because the first point in `old_df` and `combined_df` (i.e. `old_df.loc[1,:]`,`combined_df.loc[1,:]`) should have the color and marker of `'blue'` and `'x'`, respectivly.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why, but somehow using `.iloc` in the `ax.scatter` results in unpredictable behavior.  All I had to do was remove the `.iloc` method and replace it with a dictionary mapping (i.e. `c=ax_color.iloc[i]` to `c=colors[thing['Bar_Type']]`) everything works fine!

A working example of the desired result:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as tkr
from scipy.stats import probplot

#Raw Data
area_old = [7603.4897489697905, 2941.7094279413577, 8153.896678990219, 7289.99097646249, 8620.196237363853, 11619.546945954673, 8458.80648310436, 7161.530990460888, 28486.298572761007, 4928.4856128268875, 4219.122621992603, 31687.155529782176]

combined = [7603.4897489697905, 2941.7094279413577, 8153.896678990219, 7289.99097646249, 8620.196237363853, 11619.546945954673, 8458.80648310436, 7161.530990460888, 28486.298572761007, 4928.4856128268875, 4219.122621992603, 31687.155529782176, 3059.4357099599456, 3348.0415691055823, 4839.023360449559, 4398.877634354169, 29269.67455441528, 11058.400909555028, 18266.34679952683, 16641.3446048029, 24983.586163502885, 5811.868753338233]

#Attributes to map colors and markers to
lt_bt = ['r','s','s','r','r','u','r','s','r','r','s','r']
combined_bt =['r','s','s','r','r','u','r','s','r','r','s','r','u','u','r','s','r','s','r','r','r','u']

#Get Probability plot Data
a = probplot(area_old,dist='norm', plot=None)
b= probplot(combined,dist='norm', plot=None)

#Colors and Markers to use
colors = {'r':'red','s':'blue', 'u':'green'}
markers = {'r':'*','s':'x', 'u':'o'}

#Create Dataframe to combine raw data, attributes and sort
old_df = pd.DataFrame(area_old, columns=['Long Term Sites: N=12'])
old_df['Bar_Type'] = lt_bt
old_df = old_df.sort_values(by='Long Term Sites: N=12')
old_df['quart']=a[0][0]

#Pandas series of colors for plotting on subplot 'ax'
ax_color = old_df.loc[:,'Bar_Type'].apply(lambda x: colors[x])

#Create Dataframe to combine raw data, attributes and sort   
combined_df = pd.DataFrame(combined, columns=['ALL SITES N=22'])
combined_df['Bar_Type'] = combined_bt
combined_df = combined_df.sort_values(by='ALL SITES N=22')
combined_df['quart']=b[0][0]

#Pandas series of colors for plotting on subplot 'ax1'
ax1_color = combined_df.loc[:,'Bar_Type'].apply(lambda x: colors[x])

#Legend Handles
undif = plt.Line2D([0,0],[0,1], color='green',marker='o',linestyle=' ')
reatt = plt.Line2D([0,0],[0,1], color='red',marker='*',linestyle=' ')
sep = plt.Line2D([0,0],[0,1], color='blue',marker='x',linestyle=' ')


fig,(ax,ax1) = plt.subplots(ncols=2,sharey=True)

#Plot each data point seperatly with different markers and colors
for i, thing in old_df.iterrows():
    ax.scatter(thing['quart'],thing['Long Term Sites: N=12'],c=colors[thing['Bar_Type']],marker=markers[thing['Bar_Type']],zorder=10,s=50)
del i, thing

for i , thing in combined_df.iterrows():
    ax1.scatter(thing['quart'],thing['ALL SITES N=22'],c=colors[thing['Bar_Type']],marker=markers[thing['Bar_Type']],zorder=10,s=50)
del i, thing

ax.set_title('LONG TERM SITES N=12')
ax1.set_title('ALL SITES N=22')
ax1.set_ylabel('')
ax.set_ylabel('TOTAL EDDY AREA, IN METERS SQUARED')
ax.set_ylim(0,35000)
ax.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(tkr.FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: format(int(x), ',')))

legend = ax.legend([reatt,sep,undif],["Reattachment","Separation", "Undifferentiated"],loc=2,title='Bar Type',fontsize='x-small')

plt.setp(legend.get_title(),fontsize='x-small')

ax.set_xlabel('QUANTILES')
ax1.set_xlabel('QUANTILES')
plt.tight_layout()
```